# Listing products created at specific date in Magento SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I need to list the products based on created date, How to filter the list based on created at in the following code

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$complexFilter = array(
'complex_filter' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'type',
        'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple,configurable')
    )
)
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);
var_dump ($result);
```

key as created at and value as some date. How to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$complexFilter = array(
'complex_filter' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'type',
        'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple,configurable')
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'created_at',
        'value' => array('key' => 'from', 'value' => '2015-01-01 00:00:00')
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'created_at',
        'value' => array('key' => 'to', 'value' => '2016-12-31 23:59:59')
    )     
)
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);
var_dump ($result);
```

> There are quite a few filter operators available which directly
>   correspond to SQL operators, since that's what they are translated to
>   internally.

1. from => After the given timestamp
2. to => Before the given timestamp
3. like => Like the given text (SQL syntax, using % for wildcards)
4. nlike => Not like the given text (SQL syntax)
5. eq =>   Equal to the given value
6. neq =>  Not equal to the given value
7. in =>   In the given array
8. nin =>  Not in the given array
9. null => Is null
10. notnull => Is not null
11. gt =>  Greater than
12. lt =>  Less than
13. gteq =>    Greater than or equal to
14. lteq =>    Less than or equal to

You can check  Web services API filter operators [here](https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/web-services-api-filter-operators)

Answer (score 0):

The big question is...

**How to use the operator 'notnull' (or 'null')?**

**Possible solutions:**

- value = "notnull"
- value = ""
- value = null
- value = "true"
- value = "1"
- don't use a complex filter in this case

Who knows?